# Logstash convert date duration from string to hours

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have a column like this:

```
business_time_left
3 Hours 24 Minutes
59 Minutes
4 Days 23 Hours 58 Minutes
0 Seconds
1 Hour
```

and so on..

What I want to do in Logstash is to convert this entirely into hours.
So mu value should entirety convert to something like

```
business_time_left
    3.24
    0.59
    119.58
    0 
    1
```

Is this possible?

My config file:

```
http_poller {
    urls => {
    snowinc => {
    url => "https://service-now.com"
    user => "your_user"
    password => "yourpassword"
    headers => {Accept => "application/json"}
    }
}
request_timeout => 60
metadata_target => "http_poller_metadata"
schedule => { cron => "* * * * * UTC"}
codec => "json"
}
}
filter
   {
   json {source => "result" }
   split{ field => ["result"] }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["yourelastuicIP"]
    index => "inc"
    action=>update
    document_id => "%{[result][number]}"
    doc_as_upsert =>true
}
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Sample Json input data, when the url is hit.

```
{"result":[
{
"made_sla":"true",
"Type":"incident resolution p3",
"sys_updated_on":"2019-12-23 05:00:00"
"business_time_left":" 59 Minutes"} ,
{
"made_sla":"true",
"Type":"incident resolution l1.5 p4",
"sys_updated_on":"2019-12-24 07:00:00"
"business_time_left":"3 Hours 24 Minutes"}]}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you had success with my suggested approach? Is the intention behind it clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Is this possible?
>
> A: Yes.

Assuming your json- and split-filters are working correctly and the field *business_time_left* holds a single value like you showed (e.g. *4 Days 23 Hours 58 Minutes*) I personally would do the following:

First, make sure that your data is in a kind of pattern meaning, you standardize the "quantity-descriptions". This means that the minutes are always labeled as "Minutes" not Mins, min or whatever.

Nextup, you can parse the field with the grok-filter like so:

```
filter{
  grok{
    match => { "business_time_left" => "(%{INT:calc.days}\s+Days)?%{SPACE}?(%{INT:calc.hours}\s+Hours)?%{SPACE}?(%{INT:calc.minutes}\s+Minutes)?%{SPACE}?(%{INT:calc.seconds}\s+Seconds)?%{SPACE}?" }
  }
}
```

This will extract all available values into the desired fields, e.g. calc.days. The **?** character prevents that grok fails if e.g. there are no seconds. You can test the pattern on [this site](https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result).

With the data extracted, you can implement a ruby filter to aggregate the numeric values like so (untested though):

```
ruby{
  code => '
    days = event.get("calc.days")
    hours = event.get("calc.hours")
    minutes = event.get("calc.minutes")

    sum = 0

    if days
      days_numeric = days.to_i
      days_as_hours = days_numeric * 24
      sum += days_as_hours
    end

    if hours
      sum += hours.to_i
    end

    if minutes
      sum += (minutes.to_i / 100)
    end

    # seconds and so on ...

    event.set("business_time_left_as_hours", sum)
 '
}
```

So basically you check if the values are present and add them to a sum with **your custom logic**.

```
event.set("business_time_left_as_hours", sum) will set the result as a new field to the document.
```

These code snippets are not intended to be working out of the box they are just hints. So please check the documentations about the ruby filter, ruby coding in general and so on.

I hope I could help you.